# Can't redirect nginx HTTP traffic to HTTPS

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

here's my nginx.conf:

```
upstream blah_upstream {
    server web:7000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blah.com www.blah.com;

    # redict to HTTPS for all requests
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443    ssl;
    server_name   blah_upstream;
    server_tokens off;

    # generated with help of certbot
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/blah.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/blah.com/privkey.pem;
    include             /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://blah_upstream;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/public/;
    }
}
```

this works for `http://www.blah.com` -> `https://www.blah.com` (it redirects fine).

however `http://blah.com` -> `https://blah_upstream` which of course absolutely doesn't work.

what am I doing wrong? I don't understand why it would work for the www version and not the other.

I tried switching the `server_name` order in

`server_name blah.com www.blah.com;`

but that didn't work either.

Comment: Could you add details what happens rather than just saying "doesn't work". There are many possible reasons it's not working - for example, maybe the SSL cert is not valid for both domains. But without the error details, it's hard to know.

Comment: Well as I mentioned: `http://blah.com` -> resolves to -> `https://blah_upstream` in my browser, whereas when adding the `www`, the redirect works fine to HTTPS version. The site passes the [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com) test with an A, so doesn't appear to be the cert.

Comment: it is literally redirecting to `"https://blah_upstream"`, which isn't a valid URL

Comment: you are using proxy_pass at / where you have url http://blah_upstream. So it will be using that in url.

Comment: that doesn’t make sense. HTTPS connections at https:// blah.com are working fine

Comment: Use `curl -I http://blah.com` to see the value of the `Location` header in the first redirection. When testing with a browser, do you clear its cache between tests?

Comment: @lollercoaster thy change `server_name` from `server_name   blah_upstream;` to `server_name  blah.com www.blah.com blah_upstream;`

Comment: ah, yes. `curl -I` revealed that indeed the redirect was correct after hitting `http://blah.com`. clearing the cache did the trick...so silly of me. @RichardSmith if you want to submit an answer I'll accept!